# malloc for struct and pointer in C

Tags: c, memory-management

Suppose I want to define a structure representing length of the vector and its values as:

```
struct Vector{
    double* x;
    int n;
};
```

Now, suppose I want to define a vector y and allocate memory for it.

```
struct Vector *y = (struct Vector*)malloc(sizeof(struct Vector));
```

My search over the internet show that I should allocate the memory for x separately.

```
y->x = (double*)malloc(10*sizeof(double));
```

But, it seems that I am allocating the memory for y->x twice, one while allocating memory for y and the other while allocating memory for y->x, and it seems a waste of memory.
It is very much appreciated if let me know what compiler really do and what would be the right way to
initialize both y, and y->x.

Comment: As pointed out eminently by paxdiablo, please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C. I'll never understand why everyone feels a need to do so. :(

Comment: @unwind, maybe they're old C++ programmers upgrading to C :-)

Comment: @unwind When using Nvidia's nvcc compiler on C code, if I don't cast the result of malloc, it throws an error.

Comment: @Nubcake According to [this link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/508479/nvcc-forces-c-compilation-of-cu-files/) that might be because nvcc runs the underlying compiler in C++ mode, due to their CUDA interface being C++. In C, you will not get errors for this. In C++ `void *` does not automatically convert to other pointers, and the cast is needed (or, just don't use `malloc()` in C++, of course).

Comment: @unwind Yep, I later found about this :) Just wanted to state a situation where if you didn't cast the result then it would thrown an error.

Comment: @unwind but does `extern "C"` allow you to cast `void*` implicitly to something else while compiling with C++?

Comment: @TarickWelling No, I really don't think so. In C++ it's not allowed, but in C it is (and in my opinion this is a good thing in C, code with lots of casts is worse).

Answer (score 194, accepted):

No, you're *not* allocating memory for `y->x` twice.

Instead, you're allocating memory for the structure (which includes a pointer) *plus* something for that pointer to point to.

Think of it this way:

```
         1          2
        +-----+    +------+
y------>|  x------>|  *x  |
        |  n  |    +------+
        +-----+
```

You actually need the *two* allocations (`1` and `2`) to store everything you need.

Additionally, your type should be `struct Vector *y` since it's a pointer, and you should never cast the return value from `malloc` in C.

It can hide certain problems you don't want hidden, and C is perfectly capable of implicitly converting the `void*` return value to any other pointer.

And, of course, you probably want to encapsulate the creation of these vectors to make management of them easier, such as with having the following in a header file `vector.h`:

```c
struct Vector {
    double *data;    // Use readable names rather than x/n.
    size_t size;
};

struct Vector *newVector(size_t sz);
void delVector(struct Vector *vector);
//void setVectorItem(struct Vector *vector, size_t idx, double val);
//double getVectorItem(struct Vector *vector, size_t idx);
```

Then, in `vector.c`, you have the actual functions for managing the vectors:

```c
#include "vector.h"

// Atomically allocate a two-layer object. Either both layers
// are allocated or neither is, simplifying memory checking.

struct Vector *newVector(size_t sz) {
    // First, the vector layer.

    struct Vector *vector = malloc(sizeof (struct Vector));
    if (vector == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // Then data layer, freeing vector layer if fail.

    vector->data = malloc(sz * sizeof (double));
    if (vector->data == NULL) {
        free(vector);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Here, both layers worked. Set size and return.

    vector->size = sz;
    return vector;
}

void delVector(struct Vector *vector) {
    // Can safely assume vector is NULL or fully built.

    if (vector != NULL) {
        free(vector->data);
        free(vector);
    }
}
```

By encapsulating the vector management like that, you ensure that vectors are either fully built or not built at all - there's *no* chance of them being half-built.

It also allows you to totally change the underlying data structures in future without affecting clients. For example:

- if you wanted to make them sparse arrays to trade off space for speed.
- if you wanted the data saved to persistent storage whenever changed.
- if you wished to ensure all vector elements were initialised to zero.
- if you wanted to separate the vector size from the vector capacity for efficiency<sup>(1)</sup>.

You could also add more functionality such as safely setting or getting vector values (see commented code in the header), as the need arises.

For example, you could (as one option) silently ignore setting values outside the valid range and return zero if getting those values. Or you could raise an error of some description, or attempt to automatically expand the vector under the covers<sup>(1)</sup>.

---

In terms of using the vectors, a simple example is something like the following (very basic) `main.c`

```c
#include "vector.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    Vector myvec = newVector(42);
    myvec.data[0] = 2.718281828459;
    delVector(myvec);
}
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> That potential for an expandable vector bears further explanation.

Many vector implementations separate capacity from size. The former is how many elements you can use before a re-allocation is needed, the latter is the actual vector size (always <= the capacity).

When expanding, you want to generally expand in such a way that you're not doing it a lot, since it can be an expensive operation. For example, you could add 5% more than was strictly necessary so that, in a loop continuously adding one element, it doesn't have to re-allocate for every single item.

Comment: Tremble at my ASCII art skillage :-)

Comment: In if(retval == NULL), retval should be retVal

Comment: @paxdiablo Thank you for the clear explanation, and the wonderfull idea of creating a function.
Can you please add to the code a `main` showing how to call `newVector()`?

Comment: @MABisk: done. I also added a bit more exposition on some other aspects.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thank you so much. You realy rewrote the whole answer!

Answer (score 5):

The first time around, you allocate memory for `Vector`, which means the variables `x`,`n`.

However `x` **doesn't yet point to anything useful**.

So that is why **second allocation is needed as well**.

Answer (score 4):

In principle you're doing it correct already. For what you want you do need two `malloc()`s.

Just some comments:

```
struct Vector y = (struct Vector*)malloc(sizeof(struct Vector));
y->x = (double*)malloc(10*sizeof(double));
```

should be

```
struct Vector *y = malloc(sizeof *y); /* Note the pointer */
y->x = calloc(10, sizeof *y->x);
```

In the first line, you allocate memory for a Vector object. `malloc()` returns a pointer to the allocated memory, so y must be a Vector pointer. In the second line you allocate memory for an array of 10 doubles.

In C you don't need the explicit casts, and writing `sizeof *y` instead of `sizeof(struct Vector)` is better for type safety, and besides, it saves on typing.

You can rearrange your struct and do a single `malloc()` like so:

```
struct Vector{    
    int n;
    double x[];
};
struct Vector *y = malloc(sizeof *y + 10 * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: "saves on typing" is never a valid argument for programming decisions. The real reason you would take *y is for safety reasons, ensuring that you allocate as much space as needed for the corresponding variable.

Comment: @Lundin I've updated my answer, but to me the "type safety" argument is _almost_ in the same league as writing `if(NULL == foo)`

Comment: @Lundin Writing `sizeof *y` helps you fight errors like writing `sizeof(Vector)` when you meant `sizeof(Matrix)`. How often do you make mistakes like those? How quickly do you find and fix them when you do?
I agree that it increases type safety, and I do write `sizeof *y` in my own code, but it is _almost_ as paranoid as writing `if(NULL == foo)` to prevent typos on the `==`.

Comment: @Wernsey, why is `struct Vector *y = malloc(sizeof *y);` the same as `struct Vector *y = malloc(sizeof(struct Vector));`

Does `*y` dereference to the type Vector somehow?

Comment: @ShmuelKamensky They are functionally equivalent. `y` is a pointer to `struct Vector` so `sizeof *y` is saying "size of what y points to", so `sizeof struct Vector`.

Comment: @Wernsey, wow it's simple when you say it like that. Thanks!

Comment: @ShmuelKamensky In some other discussion i was told that in this context the `*y` is in unevaluated context, so not dereferenced. Could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35088909/4416551

Answer (score 3):

Few points

`struct Vector y = (struct Vector*)malloc(sizeof(struct Vector));` is wrong

it should be `struct Vector *y = (struct Vector*)malloc(sizeof(struct Vector));` since `y` holds pointer to `struct Vector`.

1st `malloc()` only allocates memory enough to hold Vector structure (which is pointer to double + int)

2nd `malloc()` actually allocate memory to hold 10 double.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate memory for `struct Vector` you just allocate memory for pointer `x`, i.e. for space, where its value, which contains address, will be placed. So such way you do not allocate memory for the block, on which `y.x` will reference.

Answer (score 1):

First malloc allocates memory for struct, including memory for x (pointer to double). Second malloc allocates memory for double value wtich x points to.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually do this in a single malloc by allocating for the Vector and the array at the same time. Eg:

```
struct Vector y = (struct Vector*)malloc(sizeof(struct Vector) + 10*sizeof(double));
y->x = (double*)((char*)y + sizeof(struct Vector));
y->n = 10;
```

This allocates Vector 'y', then makes y->x point to the extra allocated data immediate after the Vector struct (but in the same memory block).

If resizing the vector is required, you should do it with the two allocations as recommended. The internal y->x array would then be able to be resized while keeping the vector struct 'y' intact.

Comment: Why did  you type cast y to char specifically? Why not (double*)y + sizeof(struct Vector)?

Comment: sizeof returns the struct size in bytes, and the pointer arithmetic '+' operator will add to the 'y' pointer is multiples of the sizeof(*y). If we did as you did above, y would be increased by sizeof(double)*sizeof(struct), which is too much. Casting y to char* lets us increment y by sizeof(char)*sizeof(struct) = 1*sizeof(struct)

Comment: Don't do this. It does not ensure that `y->x` is properly aligned to hold a `double`. If it's not, you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

When you `malloc(sizeof(struct_name))` it automatically allocates memory for the full size of the struct, you don't need to malloc each element inside.

Use `-fsanitize=address` flag to check how you used your program memory.

Comment: Wrong.
x is just a pointer, you have to allocate memory for the value x points to.
Read other answer to get more details.
(ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14768280/5441253)