# Malloc statement giving segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

For a project I am learning to use malloc/realloc in c, but I cannot figure out why this code gives me a seg fault!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct word_data word_data_t;
typedef struct data data_t;
typedef struct index_data index_data_t; 

struct word_data {
  int docunumber;
  int freq;
};

struct data {
  char *word;
  int total_docs;
word_data_t *data;
};

struct index_data {
  data_t *index_data_array;
};
/* Inside a function called from main */
index_data_t *index_data=NULL;
index_data->index_data_array = (data_t*)malloc(sizeof(*(index_data- >index_data_array))*INITIAL_ALLOCATION);
```

Im seriously stuck for ideas after trying a bunch of stuff and searching stackoverflow! any info helps!

Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks for your help guys! but im still running into a seg fault later in the program, probably because of a similar mistake, but I've tried a bunch of stuff and cant get it to work, here are all my malloc/realloc calls:

```
index_data = (index_data_t*)malloc(sizeof(*index_data)*INITIAL_ALLOCATION);
index_data->index_data_array = (data_t*)malloc(sizeof(*index_data- >index_data_array)*INITIAL_ALLOCATION);
index_data->index_data_array = realloc(index_data->index_data_array, current_size_outer_array*sizeof(*(index_data->index_data_array)))
index_data->index_data_array[index].word=malloc(strlen(word)+1);
index_data->index_data_array[index].word=entered_word;
index_data->index_data_array[index].data = (word_data_t *)malloc(sizeof(word_data_t)*INITIAL_ALLOCATION);
index_data->index_data_array[index].total_docs=atoi(word);
index_data->index_data_array[index].data = realloc(index_data-  >index_data_array[index].data, current_size_inner_array*(sizeof(*(index_data-   >index_data_array[index].data))))
index_data->index_data_array[index].data->docunumber = docunum;
index_data->index_data_array[index].data->freq = freq;
```

then when I go to print out something later:

```
printf("%d\n", index_data->index_data_array[0].total_docs);
```

I get a segfault, have I missed a malloc again or similar?

Thanks

Comment: `index_data_t *index_data=NULL; index_data->index_data_array = ...` so `NULL->index_data_array`

Comment: `malloc()` is highly unlikely to cause a segfault. The problem here is that you're dereferencing `index_data`, which is a null pointer

Comment: Inside your sizeof() you are trying to access index_data, which is marked as NULL in there previous statement.

Comment: @hashdefine the argument of `sizeof` is unevaluated, so it is permitted to dereference null inside it

Answer (score 2):

- you don't need all these typedefs
- you don't need to cast
- `sizeof *ptr` gives the size of the *object* that `ptr` *points to*
- IMHO the code without casts&typedefs is much clearer:

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct thing {
        int type;
        char name[13];
        };

struct box {
        unsigned nthing;
        struct thing *things;
        };

struct box *make_box(unsigned thingcount)
{
struct box *thebox;

thebox = malloc (sizeof *thebox);    
if (!thebox) return NULL;

thebox->things = malloc (thingcount * sizeof *thebox->things);    
if (!thebox->things) { free(thebox); return NULL; }

thebox->nthing = thingcount;
return thebox;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to access an element which is from NULL address space. 
Try this :

```
index_data = (index_data_t*)malloc(sizeof(*(index_data)));
```

So on, you can fill your array like :

```
index_data->index_data_array = (data_t*)malloc(sizeof(*(index_data->index_data_array))*INITIAL_ALLOCATION);
```

Comment: right, makes sense, but I'm a little confused now

I understand that I've made it a null pointer, does that mean after this malloc statement I now cant use the array I have malloc'd? Should I just not cast this to a null pointer? Or if not, how do I now go add something to say index_data->index_data_array.word?

Comment: it could be sizeof(index_data_t) or sizeof(struct index_data), isn't it?

Edit: Oh, I'm wrong. I had missed that you declared an index_data variable of type index_data_t. Then it's Ok although naming both the struct and the variable the same is a bit confusing

Comment: @sharcashmo you do not have to mention the type.

Comment: I know, I edited my comment a minute ago. I missed that index_data was the name of the variable :D

Comment: I know the answer get a lil bit confusing but I do not like to modify too much to do it in @Tehmo3's fashion.

Comment: @cadgas 
Thanks for your help cagdas, I really am confused here, how would I access these sub-struct elements to give them data? doing it as I normally would (index_data->index_data_array->etc) doesn't work since its a null pointer?

Comment: For sub-struct elements you'll also need them to be filled via malloc.  Check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768230/malloc-for-struct-and-pointer-in-c

Comment: @cagdas thanks! I think I understand that part but I seem to still be getting an error... I've updated my post with some new info if you could take a look I would be very thankful!